# Slash missing on API usage page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, stackapps

On [this](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage) page, I noticed the following:

[image: There's something missing...]

It seems to me that there should be a slash in between the `s` and the `{`, so that it reads:

> `/tags/{tag}...`

Comment: Also, that route and the one above it are out of alphabetical order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next build will fix this truly egregious oversight.